# Spring batch using two data Sources

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing, data-migration

I'm working on a Spring Batch project where I need to use two different data sources. I'm planning to use **RepositoryItemReader** and **RepositoryItemWriter** for reading and writing to these databases. However, I couldn't find any documentation on how to configure Spring Batch for this specific scenario.

Additionally, when I added JPA configuration, Spring Batch seems to default to using MySQL for its internal operations. How can I configure Spring Batch to work with two data sources and prevent this default behavior when using JPA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `@EnableBatchProcessing`, you can configure the datasource you want for the `JobRepository` by setting the `dataSourceRef` attribute. For example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing(dataSourceRef = "batchDataSource", transactionManagerRef = "jpaTransactionManager")
public static class JobConfiguration {

}
```

The equivalent to that with the programmatic approach is by overriding `DefaultBatchConfiguration#getDataSource()`.

The same datasource can then be set on the item reader and writer.

Comment: It worked, but the issue is that it didn't write any data to the database; the database connection is not an issue.

Comment: i'll post my code in a different question

Comment: No need for another question, you can update this one.

Comment: [New question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77196268/spring-batch-repositoryitemwriter-doesnt-write-data-to-database)
I already did, please can you assist me on this it would be very helpful